# WPF- Not able to Bind XamDatagrid with observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am doing developing one application where i am using infragistics and wpf to display data.
My code looks like this

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="MyItemContol"  ItemsSource="{Binding ViewSetList}" 
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <igDP:XamDataGrid  DataSource="{Binding ViewSetList}" >
                    <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                        <igDP:FieldLayout>
                            <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>

                                <igDP:Field Name="PARAMETER">
                                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                        <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" />
                                    </igDP:Field.Settings>

                                </igDP:Field>

                                <igDP:Field Name="VALUE">
                                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                        <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False"   />
                                    </igDP:Field.Settings>
                                </igDP:Field>
                                <igDP:Field Name="UNIT">
                                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                        <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" />
                                    </igDP:Field.Settings>
                                </igDP:Field>
                                <igDP:Field Name="INSTANCE">
                                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                        <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" />
                                    </igDP:Field.Settings>
                                </igDP:Field>

                            </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                        </igDP:FieldLayout>
                    </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>

                </igDP:XamDataGrid>


            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

This xaml file contains four fields Parameter,value,unit and instances.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window 
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Parameters> viewSetList = new 
        ObservableCollection<Parameters>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Add data to the collection
        viewSetList.Add(new Parameters() { PARAMETER="abc",  INSTANCE="def" , UNIT="hhshhd", VALUE="hahha" });


    }


public class Parameters:  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string parameterName = string.Empty;

    public string PARAMETER
    {
        get { return parameterName; }
        set { parameterName = value; }
    }
    private string parameterValue = string.Empty;

    public string VALUE
    {
        get { return parameterValue; }
        set { parameterValue = value; }
    }
    private string parameterUnit = string.Empty;

    public string UNIT
    {
        get { return parameterUnit; }
        set { parameterUnit = value; }
    }
    private string instance = string.Empty;

    public string INSTANCE
    {
        get { return instance; }
        set { instance = value; }
    }       

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void onPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

When i executed it is displaying only blank screen.  But i have included  ItemsSource="{Binding ViewSetList}"  in the xaml file. Could any one tell me why the binding is not happening?

Should i need bind XamDataGrid also?

Help will be highly appreciated.

THANKS

Comment: There's too much wrong with the code, and you didn't bother to provide a good [mcve], so it's not practical to try to provide an actual answer. But: you can only bind to properties. And the properties need to be public. And C# is case-sensitive, so `ViewSetList` is not the same as `viewSetList`. And `{Binding ViewSetList}` isn't going to be valid in the context of an _item_ in your control. You should start by focusing on those issues. If you still need help, post a question that includes a good [mcve] and is more specific about what you've already done to debug and what you need help with

Comment: i made it public and changed binding to viewSetList. But still i am getting blank screen

Comment: Those aren't the only problems in your code. Those aren't even the only problems I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I could not get what you are  saying?

Comment: Sorry you can't understand my comments. But, please note that the statement _"I could not get what you are saying"_ doesn't provide any useful feedback as to what _specifically_ you don't understand or how I might reword what I said so you can understand it. Please work harder to be precise in your communication and provide all necessary detail to move that communication in a forward direction.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I will improve myself. It would be help full i u would have pointed  me "what i did wrong in my code"

Comment: I did point out several problems in your code. Read my first comment above.

Comment: @sampatnayak If you changed your code, please update the code here as well. So that we can see, what you have done and did not have to guess what the (new) problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you put the `XamDataGrid` inside an `ItemsControl`? You don't need the `ItemsControl`.

Remove it and make `ViewSetList` a *public property* and set the `DataContext` of the window to itself:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Parameters> _viewSetList = new ObservableCollection<Parameters>();
    public ObservableCollection<Parameters> ViewSetList { get { return _viewSetList; } }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Add data to the collection
        _viewSetList.Add(new Parameters() { PARAMETER = "abc", INSTANCE = "def", UNIT = "hhshhd", VALUE = "hahha" });

        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

You can then bind the `XamDataGrid` to the property:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding ViewSetList}" >
                <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                    <igDP:FieldLayout>
                        <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                            <igDP:Field Name="PARAMETER">
                                <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                    <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" />
                                </igDP:Field.Settings>
                            </igDP:Field>
                            <igDP:Field Name="VALUE">
                                <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                    <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False"   />
                                </igDP:Field.Settings>
                            </igDP:Field>
                            <igDP:Field Name="UNIT">
                                <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                    <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" />
                                </igDP:Field.Settings>
                            </igDP:Field>
                            <igDP:Field Name="INSTANCE">
                                <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                    <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" />
                                </igDP:Field.Settings>
                            </igDP:Field>

                        </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                    </igDP:FieldLayout>
                </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</Grid>
```

You cannot bind to private fields.